# Calculating maximum permissible track amperage for intrinsic safe PCB

Tags: pcb-design, temperature, safety, pcb-layers, trace

I'm reading IEC 60079-11 standard (Equipment protection by intrinsic safety "i") which discusses how to design intrinsic safe circuit boards. In section 5.6.4 it talks about permissible termperature of copper tracks/boards and gives an example. Hence I'm not expert on PCB design, I cannot figure it out how the current calculated. Here is the example provided in the text and the reference table. Can somebody please explain how the values calculated in the example?

[image]

Example provided in the text:
[image]

Answer (score 2):

> *I cannot figure it out how the current calculated*

They're probably not calculated because they include strong safety margins for maintaining intrinsic safety thus, the current won't produce an excessive over-temperature (for a given track width) that might ignite a contacting gas. It's highly likely (that along with spark ignition testing on various gases), these currents were deemed "infallible" in that a particular ignitable gas couldn't ignite it AND, this testing was quite likely to have been done in a small ignition chamber hence no calculations. I've seen the chambers used for spark testing and I suspect a similar method was used after all, why not.